# How to compare two lists in python without changing the order

Tags: python, list

I want to compare list `a` with list `b` and find the common elements but the result list should have the order of list `a`.

```
a = ['apple','ora','bab','ooo']
b = ['ooo','nnn','apple','ora']
c = set(a) & set(b)
print(c)
set(['ooo', 'apple', 'ora'])
```

The result which am expecting is `['apple','ora','ooo']` the order as in list `a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
a = ['apple','ora','bab','ooo']
b = ['ooo','nnn','apple','ora']
common = [x for x in a if x in b]
print(common)
# ['apple', 'ora', 'ooo']
```

Comment: In-case if element repeats in first list, then in output it will also repeat.( will work for given input)